# Is distribution of drugs in itself a crime?

Tags: criminal-law, england-and-wales, drugs

You always seem to hear of people being done with "possession with intent to distribute," rather than actual distribution. Why is this?

Comment: The title and the body of the question seem to be asking different questions.  The "why" question in the body would appear not to be related to the law but to practicalities.  It is a lot more likely that the police catch Big Boss in possession of a large amount of drugs than that they catch him actively distributing those drugs since distribution is generally done by lower level lackeys.

Comment: They're very closely related questions, and a good quality answer IMO could not address one without the other.

Comment: You may be able to answer your own question by reading through the [Misuse of Drugs Act 1971](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1971/38/contents).

Comment: holding enough of an illicit substance it typically itself enough to imply intent to distribute.  The "why" of drug laws is control of certain segments of the population, this is another way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, distribution of controlled drugs is itself a standalone offence.

Under the [*Misuse of Drugs Act 1971*, s. 4(1)](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1971/38/section/4), it is an offence to supply or offer to supply a controlled drug to another. And [*supplying* includes distributing](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1971/38/section/37).

Possession with intent to supply is also an offence. [Section 5(3)](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1971/38/section/5) makes it an offence for a person to have a controlled drug in their possession, "with intent to supply it to another."

[The Crown Prosecution Service says](https://www.cps.gov.uk/legal-guidance/drug-offences):

> Where the evidence supports a charge of supplying or possessing controlled drugs of any class with intent to supply, this is to be preferred to a simple possession charge.

Answer (score 1):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

Media descriptions often diverge from the wording of statutes. The Washington law, [RCW 69.50.401](https://app.leg.wa.gov/rcw/default.aspx?cite=69.50.401) says that

> Except as authorized by this chapter, it is unlawful for any person to
> manufacture, deliver, or possess with intent to manufacture or
> deliver, a controlled substance.

The wording poses an interpretive problem. It is clear that possessing with intent to manufacture or deliver is included in the crime ("deliver" is actually [defined](https://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=69.50.101) as "the actual or constructive transfer from one person to another of a substance, whether or not there is an agency relationship", thus "deliver to yourself" is not "delivery as defined in this chapter). This distinguishes possession with intent to deliver from simple possession.
The wording might also be thought to also include a restriction on "manufacture" i.e. only manufacture with intend to deliver, vs. "simple manufacturing" (for personal use), but this is highly implausible, first because of the lack of a comma indicating that "with intent to manufacture or deliver" applies to all three conjuncts and not just the last one, second (relatedly since the interpretative principle "the last antecedent rule" limits the modifier to the last conjunct, third because such an interpretation would be pointless ("manufacture with intent to manufacture; deliver with intent to deliver" would be pointlessly redundant. Finally, the phrasing
"possess with intent" exists because there is a [separate lesser crime](https://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=69.50.4013) of simple possession, so this statute has to be written to specifically identify mere *possession* as not subject to *this* penalty.

As to why the law was modified to impose a lesser penalty on simple possession, that's a question of historical politics, but probably relates to the idea that consumers are less culpable w.r.t. a wrong than the promulgators of the wrong.

Answer (score 0):

[germany](/questions/tagged/germany)

[Trade (Handel), Import, Sale (Verkauf), handing out (Abgabe), and buying (kauf) of any drug under the BtmG without a license is punishable under BtMG §29](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/btmg_1981/__29.html). Especially *sonst in den Verkehr bringt* (any other means to put in distribution) is the catch-all phrase in this regard: you let them sit on your counter for anyone to take? You put them in distribution by any other means, and thus can be punished with up to 5 years under §29(1).

So **yes**, in Germany any form of distributing drugs without license is a criminal act.